# Switching from Windows to forms authentication

Tags: c#, asp.net, authentication, webforms

I've got windows authentication in one of web projects I've been working on. Due to all other have forms authentication, I want to implement it also in this particular project. I've followed this article http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/37558/Windows-Authentication-Using-Form-Authentication and added new login page, but after running project I've got redirected to the same default page it used before.

Here's changes which I made to web.config:

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="login.aspx"></forms>
</authentication>

<authorization>
  <deny users="?"/>
</authorization>
```

What are my possible mistakes?

Comment: Did you modify the settings in IIS to disable Windows Authentication?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When switching to *Forms Authentication* from *Windows Authentication*, you'll need to disable Windows Authentication in IIS for your Application. It doesn't do it for you automatically when you enable Forms Authentication in the web.config.

You most likely have both Forms and Windows Authentication enabled in IIS on your Application. I believe IIS will default to Windows Authentication in that case and bypass your login form.

To check that, you can do the following:

- Go to **IIS**
- Locate your **Application**
- Go to **Authentication**
- Adjust the following

  - Anonymous Authentication: **Enabled**
  - ASP.NET Impersonation: **Disabled**
  - Basic Authentication: **Disabled**
  - Digest Authentication: **Disabled**
  - Forms Authentication: **Enabled**
  - Windows Authentication: **Disabled**

You can also disable Anonymous Authentication if you don't want a landing page prior to logging in as well.

Comment: It seems I haven't enough rights to modify Authentication. However, both Windows and Forms Authentication are disabled. The only enabled options are Anonymous Authentication and ASP.NET Impersonation

Comment: You'll need to see if you can have Forms Authentication enabled and ASP.NET Impersonation disabled, unless you actually need that for your application implementation someplace. Your forms authentication implementation will handle authentication against Active Directory and you won't be using impersonation for that purpose at least.